# Change text on submit button after submission

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit, submit-button

Is it possible to change the text on the submit button after submission? Example the button has the word Submit and after the user submits the form, the button will now say Done. If so, how is it done?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when user submits the form? Is it processed with AJAX, or the whole page gets reloaded?

Comment: Oh, it's processed with AJAX.

Comment: Then change it in `$.ajax` success function (as technically processing can be considered done only after server reports about it).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using AJAX to process the form, you could simply have the button text change in the success callback of the [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) jQuery method like so:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        ...
        // If using an <input/> as the submit button
        $('BUTTON_SELECTOR').prop('value', 'Done');

        // If using a <button/> as the submit button
        $('BUTTON_SELECTOR').text('Done');
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible** & you can have it done with this:

```
<form name="MyForm">
<input type=button name="b1" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:document.MyForm.b1.value='Done'">
</form>
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dZthR/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id_of_button').click(function( event ) {
    $('#id_of_button').prop('value', 'Text you want to change to');
});
```

Edit: Actually, a better solution would probably be to bind it to the submit handler of the form.

Answer (score 0):

We can do by using the below code. It will make the submit button as 'Uploading please wait...' with the spinner icon.

```html
<button name='button' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary right' data-disable-with="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>Uploading please wait...">Save</button>
```