# Change value of input when input type=submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have an input like the one below:

```
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Blah">
```

I want to change the value to 'Other Text'.
When I use the .val(),attr() or .prop() jQuery method the value changes fine but when I submit, the input doesn't work any more.Just refreshes the page without doing what its supposed to.

Same result with .setAttribute method.

How do I get the input to work correctly now the value has been changed?

Comment: you want to change `value` after submit?

Comment: Default behavior for input type submit is to submit the form. If you want to disable submit use `$('form').submit(function() { return false; })`

Comment: The server-side script might be checking the value of the submit button before processing the inputs

Comment: The default behaviour of a form is to submit data, you need to tell it not to submit if you don't want it to. If you use `event.preventDefault();` in the function triggered on submit this will remove the default behaviour of posting.

Comment: @jiff want to change value then submit

Comment: Share what are you trying with `prop()`, `attr()` and `val()`. We aren't wizards with crystal balls.

Comment: @user3465217 I'm confused to why you would allow the client to input text for it to be changed before submitting... it removes the point of having them input text.... why not just send the value `Other Text` over rather than changing the clients input?

Comment: @jeff  I think you're right.  I can't do anything with it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type=button name="b1" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:document.MyForm.b1.value='Done'">
```

Source : [Change text on submit button after submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640996/change-text-on-submit-button-after-submission)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function(){
     $(this).val("OtherText");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Blah">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent submitting form or in click event of button:

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#inputbox").val("OtherText");
    //Now you can submit form manually here
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

Comment: The second code will create infinite loop because calling submit() will execute the event and the callback,

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was server side script was checking the value, so had to change the value back when clicked.

```
if ($('.submit').length > 0) {
    $('.submit').prop('value', 'Other Text');
    $('.submit').click(function(){
    $('.submit').prop('value', 'blah'); 
    });}
```

This seems to be working 'ok' now. Not ideal but works